# The texture is not tiling correctly

Tags: texturing, uv, vertices, uv-image-editor

I modeled a Model in Blender, then I added a Texture to it
with the UV Wrapper. I 'press U for a small Unwrap UV Project.
But the problem is I can seee where the Textures is Starting and ending.

[image]

Comment: If you really need help, take the time and improve your question. Correct the spelling, provide your setup, and show what you have tried so far...

Comment: Is your texture seamless? Did you take care to unwrap it properly so the seams would not be visible? You can't expect unwrapping to just work perfectly with automatic presets without putting in some effort